# Activity manager crash

Tags: android, multithreading, service, android-activity

i have some trouble with android app. I have 5 activity, broadcast receiver and service with many thread. When i pass between activities, i have some error in my logcat:

```
10-25 11:22:20.255     448-3949/? E/ActivityManager﹕ Activity Manager Crash
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown service start result: 15
        at com.android.server.am.ActiveServices.serviceDoneExecutingLocked(ActiveServices.java:1412)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.serviceDoneExecuting(ActivityManagerService.java:11398)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:830)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:1737)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

What is that? Hope somebody will telling me!

Comment: Can you show how you start your service? Do you pass multiple intents to it?

Comment: I'm guessing this line makes more sense to you: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown service start result: 15`

Comment: I start my service by different events on different activities. Call this method: 
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, ImageUploader.class);
startService(serviceIntent);

Comment: I'm understand your policy Keyser. But I just passing between activities, and don't starting service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May this help you:

**Points to Keep in Mind for `onStartCommand()`:**

**intent** The Intent supplied to `startService(Intent)`, as given. This may be null if the service is being restarted after its process has gone away, and it had previously returned anything except `START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY`.

**flags** Additional data about this start request. Currently either `0, START_FLAG_REDELIVERY, or START_FLAG_RETRY.`

**startId** A unique integer representing this specific request to start. Use with `stopSelfResult(int)` Returns.

- The return value indicates what semantics the system should use for
  the service's current started state. It may be one of the constants associated with the `START_CONTINUATION_MASK` bits

So you need to return START_STICKY, or one of the values from [Click Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_CONTINUATION_MASK)

Comment: yeah, I return  START_STICKY flag, and error has gone. Thanks a lot.